# Append a script into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I've got a little problem and I'm stucking on it for a couple of days.
I downloaded a `Javascript`calendar plugin ([Date Input](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/jasoncalendar.htm)) to add a little calendar in my form.
In this form I added a button wich add another line in this form to let user set severals dates.

```
<input type="button" value="Ajouter" onclick="ajoutChamp('creneau')" />
```

I made a little script :

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.text = "DateInput('creneau_2',true,'DD-MON-YYYY')";
$("#test").append(s);
```

But when I'm doing this, every time I press the button I've got my calendar who appears fullscreen. It's look like the script has been executed but no appened in the html page.

Little piece of my html code :

```
<table id="liste_creneau" class="add_champ">
    <tr id="tr_creneau_1">
        <td><label for="creneau_1">creneau 1</label></td>
        <td><script id="ref_date">DateInput('creneau_1', true, 'DD-MON-YYYY')</script></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Atm I wanted to append the calendar in a div but at the end the calendar will be in the table.

I have done other tests too but every piece of code I made ended the same way...

So maybe you could help me! :)

**Edit:**

Ok I made a little test

```
var g = document.getElementById('test');
var s = document.getElementById('ref_date');
nb++;
var clone = s.cloneNode(true);
var param = clone.firstChild.data.split('\'');
param[1] = 'creneau_'+nb;
clone.firstChild.data = param.join('\'');
g.appendChild(clone);
```

After that, when I click on the button, there is a script tag inserted in the div but nothing shows up. When I inspect my html page I can see it but the calendar doesn't apear...

Bye

Edouard

Comment: Oh yeah and I also tried to clone the node but the plugin didn't work because he still had a reference on the first node

Comment: Mmmh Gabe I don't use JQuery here (or maybe I should? ^^)

Comment: You sure #test exists? post more code, and does the console return any errors?

Comment: I added more code, but wich console?

Comment: Well I don't really know how to use the browser console :s

Comment: Isn't "$("#test").append(s);" jQuery?  console: a developer tool like FireBug.

Comment: @EdouardMoinard If you press F12 in Chrome/FF or IE, a webdeveloper console opens, showing you every kind of information, including problems with your code.

Comment: @agentmilindu actually this might be the problem;) Look into your console after an error like: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bla' of null`. Then you have to add jQuery as source.

Comment: You are using jquery, with this line: `$("#test").append(s);`

Comment: Ok I'm learning something I didn't knew this was jQuery :p But sadly I already had the jQuery sources in my <head>....

Comment: And the only error I've got is 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,' and I really don't know what is that :p

Comment: I found that calendar plugin Edouard Moinard used is using `document.write()` to add contents. When we dynamically adds the script( with 'DateInput' method), what it do is write the content of the  calendar to the body. Then I executed this on a page `document.write("hi");` then I checked the codes, there was just this `<html><head></head><body>hi</body></html>`. this is what happens in this case too!  Dynamically calling `DateInput` will replace the document's elements!I can't get a workaround to this. How we can help him?

Comment: Oh thanks for investigating so far :) So `document.write` override the previous html code right? Maybe with another plugin this should work?

Comment: Yes, use a new plugin, You are using jQuery, Then you can use JQuery UI! Their calender is awesome![link]http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Well I'll take a look thanks! :) If this work I'll close this! :) Thanks again!

Comment: Mmmh maybe you can help me I don't know wich file to download :s

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are not just running the date input line. It should have the same effect.

```
DateInput('creneau_2',true,'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Regardless, you could just try and do it all in jQuery rather than mixing javascript selectors.

```
$("#test").append("<script type='text/javascript'>DateInput('creneau_2',true,'DD-MON-YYYY');</script>");
```

Comment: With this code I have the same problem as I explained the calendar "overwrite" my html page and the only thing left is this calendar :s

Answer (score 0):

Well I chosen to use the jQuery-UI datepicker instead... So I guess it's solved, thanks a lot Agentminlindu and all the others :)